# How to free up memory in this case?

Tags: c++, function, class, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have one class A and one function `func` as below

```
class A
{
   int m_memA;
 public:
   A(int x):m_memA(x){}   
   std::string GetString(); 
};

A* CreateA()
{
    return new A(5);
}

bool func(std::string* stringOut)
{
   A* obj_A = CreateA();                //memory allocated in heap
   *stringOut = obj_A->GetString(); 
   if(stringOut->empty())
       {return true;}
   return false;      
} 

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    if(func(&str))        //How to free memory here?    
    {
        //do something
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do I free the memory when `func` is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see absolutely no reason for all the dynamic allocation, but you need to `delete` the `A` in `func`:

```
bool func(std::string* stringOut)
{
   A* obj_A = CreateA();                //memory allocated in heap
   *stringOut = obj_A->GetString();
   delete obj_A;                      // delete dynamically allocated object
   return stringOut->empty();    
}
```

**Edit** Since you cannot change `CreateA`, you could at least make this exception safe by using a smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr`. For example:

```
bool func(std::string* stringOut)
{
   std::unique_ptr<A> obj_A(CreateA());
   *stringOut = obj_A->GetString();
   return stringOut->empty();    
}
```

Comment: CreateA(), class A is pre-existing code. Can't do anything about it. func is in my control.

Comment: @ontherocks OK. Using a smart pointer might be a better alternative. See my edit.

Comment: So during `*stringOut = obj_A->GetString();` stringOut has the return string set (because it is dereferenced?). So deleting obj_A after it, won't lead to invalid pointers.

Comment: Are both of these identical? `return stringOut->empty();` and `return (*stringOut).empty();`

Comment: @ontherocks Yes, they are equivalent. I would actually pass a reference instead, and avoid all the `*` and/or `->`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) design pattern for your objects. It will avoid these types of memory leaks. It will even handle returns caused from exception.

Here is a better design pattern.

```
A CreateA() { return A(5); }

// RAII designed heap allocation
std::unique_ptr<A> CreateHeapA() { return std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(5)); }


bool func(std::string* stringOut)
{
   *stringOut = CreateA().GetString();        // A allocated on the stack
   //*stringOut = CreateHeapA()->GetString(); // A allocated on the heap
   return stringOut->empty();
}
```